# Only refresh table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, refresh

I been looking online for a long time for Javascript or other scripting method to accomplish this however I have yet to find anything. Everything I find seems complicated and is reloading info from a database. In my mind it should be very simple. I have a website built to display wait times for restaurants around my property. Inside the website I have a table with embedded links to text files. I use an HTA application to rewrite the text files to update the wait times. I need to automatically refresh the browser without creating the flash of the webpage reloading. Is there anyway to do this?

My coding is super basic:

```
<html>
<blah <blah> <blah>

<table>
<th> blah blah </th>
<td> <src embed something.html> </td>
<table>
 </blah </blah> </blah>
 </html>
```

If this isn't possible can I cache the background?

Comment: Read about [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: as @RayonDabre has said, this is AJAX is the answer here, but its too big a subject for us to teach you here. It shouldn't take you too much reading to work out an AJAX solution to this, and you'll be much better off with the new knowledge!

Comment: Since my page is staying on the intranet I have just thrown it up on a file server. Will AJAX require a websever to run the httprequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people have said, you have to use AJAX for that.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load), you have a very simple AJAX example that does something very similar to what you want.

You just have to set a timer to regularly update these files.
[This site](http://csouza.me/jQuery-Simple-Timer/) has a very simple library to set up a timer.

Comment: Does AJAX require the html page to be hosted on an http server to run the httprequest? I only have it on a file server because it is a simple webpage and is only being viewed internally.